# How to rotate a CGRect in Swift UI to detect collisions

Tags: swift, swiftui, 2d-games

Im working on this game where you have an airplane and there's falling balls from the sky. So to check for collisions between the airplane and the balls I created rectangles to represent their hitbox.

The checkCollision function worked normally until I tried implementing the rotationAngle the airplane has at the moment, when I do that it stops working completely.

here's my check collisions logic:

```
private func checkCollisions() {
    let airplaneRect = CGRect(
        x: airplane.x - 10,
        y: airplane.y - 60,
        width: 90,
        height: 30
    )

    for index in 0..<raindrops.count {
        let raindropRect = CGRect(
            x: raindrops[index].xPosition - raindrops[index].size / 2,
            y: raindrops[index].yPosition - raindrops[index].size / 2,
            width: raindrops[index].size,
            height: raindrops[index].size
        )

        if intersects(rect1: airplaneRect, rect2: raindropRect, angle: airplane.rotationAngle) {
            collisionDetected = true
        }
    }
}

private func intersects(rect1: CGRect, rect2: CGRect, angle: Angle) -> Bool {
    let rotatedRect1 = rect1.applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(angle.radians)))

    return rotatedRect1.intersects(rect2)
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't take this for granted but I would guess that `intersects(_:)` detects the intersection between two axis aligned rectangles. I'm not even sure `frame` is still valid after a rotation transform. I think you'll have to resort to Separating Axis Theorem collision test, or a third party library such as Box2D.

Comment: This has a number of issues: 1) the rotation in the is calculated around the origin and you probably want it to be around the center of the plane rect 2) The result of applying a CGAffineTransform to a rect results in the smallest rect that contains all of its corners. The resulting rect is thus not a rotated rectangle, but the smallest rectangle containing the the rotated rectangle! This is usually too big to be useful for hit testing.